# Dictionary<string, List<int>> to WPF GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, dictionary, .net-3.5

I would like to bind a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` to a `GridView` in a `ListView` and I'm not having much luck.

I've looked at this question: [wpf-binding-dictionarystring-liststring-to-listview-listbox-how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525333/wpf-binding-dictionarystring-liststring-to-listview-listbox-how), and this question: [dictionary-binding-to-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375281/dictionary-binding-to-listview-wpf)

But I'm not sure how to take their code and make it work for me.

Here's what I've tried:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfIdeas.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="315">
    <Grid x:Name="theGrid">
        <ListView x:Name="lv">
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<int>> lists = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lists["a"] = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        lists["b"] = new List<int>(new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9});
        lists["c"] = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

        GridView gv = new GridView();
        foreach(string k in lists.Keys)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding("[" + k + "]");
            gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
                               {
                                   DisplayMemberBinding = binding,
                                   Header = k,
                                   Width = 100
                               });
        }

        lv.ItemsSource = lists;
        lv.View = gv;
    }
}
```

How can I get the lists to display in the window, below their respective headings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution, but I'm hoping there is a better way:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfIdeas.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="315">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xdp"></XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="theGrid">
        <ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xdp}, XPath=/rows/row}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gv">
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

c#:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        protected Dictionary<string, List<int>> lists = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lists["a"] = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
            lists["b"] = new List<int>(new int[] {6, 7, 8, 9});
            lists["c"] = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

            XDocument data = new XDocument();
            data.Add(new XElement("rows"));

            int maxListLength = lists.Max(l => l.Value.Count);

            for (int index = 0; index < maxListLength; ++index )
            {
                XElement row = new XElement("row");
                foreach(string k in lists.Keys)
                {
                    XElement value = new XElement(k);
                    if(index < lists[k].Count)
                    {
                        value.Value = lists[k][index].ToString();
                    }
                    row.Add(value);
                }
                data.Root.Add(row);
            }

            (Resources["xdp"] as XmlDataProvider).Document = new XmlDocument{InnerXml = data.ToString()};

            foreach (string key in lists.Keys)
            {
                GridViewColumn gvc = new GridViewColumn();
                gvc.Header = key;
                gvc.Width = 75;
                gvc.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding { XPath = key };
                gv.Columns.Add(gvc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Better way depends on your requirements. Is using XML a requirement, otherwise I would create a collection like this: List<Dictionary<string, int?>>. Is your data dynamic, like number of columns or individual data? Is that why you do the binding in code behind?

Comment: Yes, the number of lists in the dictionary varies, as does the number of items in each list. Using XML is not a requirement, it's just the only way I've come up with so far of making the output look like I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using XAML instead of code behind, check out this example:

[Problem with MVVM. Dynamic list of grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117179/problem-with-mvvm-dynamic-list-of-grids/3118950#3118950)

Comment: Thanks, this has got me some of the way there. I'll see if I can put this into a GridView.